# android fragment transition animation

Tags: android, fragment, android-animation

I have one dialog with list of item.
on click of each item i push one fragment.
I want that fragment to load with animation.
I knew how to do animation from fragment to fragment 
but help me to apply animation when i have only one fragments
This is what i already tried, this helps to apply transition between two fragments.

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);

    DetailsFragment newFragment = DetailsFragment.newInstance();

    ft.replace(R.id.details_fragment_container, newFragment, "detailFragment");

    // Start the animated transition.
    ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

- Required common method for each item click where different fragment push.
  You have to put common method in code.
- **Method code**

```
public void pushFragments
(Fragment fragment, boolean shouldAnimate, boolean shouldAddinbackstack, String tag) { 
        FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment, tag);
        if (shouldAddinbackstack) {
            //add fragment in backstack entry
            ft.addToBackStack(tag);
        } 
        if (shouldAnimate) {
            //fragment animated 
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        } 
        ft.commit();
    }
```

- use method on item click e.g

```
DetailsFragment newFragment = DetailsFragment.newInstance();
pushFragments(newFragment, true, true, "detailsFragment");
```